# Polymer remove parent

Tags: polymer

When trying to remove a the parent element I have been able to use this line for most cases:

`Polymer.dom(Polymer.dom(this).node.domHost.parentNode).removeChild(Polymer.dom(this).node.domHost);`

Yet in some cases I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: The node to be removed is not a child of this node: [object HTMLElement]
```

I have verified the child is there and the objects look correct, but I think I am probably missing a Polymer.dom() somewhere?

Comment: I would expect this to work `Polymer.dom(Polymer.dom(this).parentNode).removeChild(Polymer.dom(this));`

Comment: I can't just use parentNode because of the layering may not get me to the next element.  So I need to do domHost to get to next polymer element.

Comment: I see. Didn't use this since a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve it for all cases that I need by doing this:

```
      var thisNode = Polymer.dom(this).node;
  Polymer.dom(Polymer.dom(thisNode.domHost).parentNode).removeChild(thisNode.domHost);
```